# How to blur part of an image in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, filter

I want to use filters in part of an image opened in inkscape. I could use filters in the whole image by clicking on the image in selecting the filter.

But I can not figure out how to apply a filter in part of an image?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What kind of image is it - a photograph, a graphic?  Is it raster or vector? Can you post an image that shows what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the image

Draw a rectangle that is half the width of the image

Blur the duplicate image and then select it together with rectangle to make a clipping mask